# Validation for required boolean attributes doesn't work

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I'm using OpenAPI 2.0 contract for my Rest service, written in Yaml, and I'm using swagger-codegen to generate the POJOs. I activated the useBeanValidation and performBeanValidation, so that the generated code (in JAVA) include the validation annotations...

In my contract I have a field of type boolean that I marked as required:

```
cancellationInd:
        description: "indicates if this is a cancellation"
        type: boolean
        required: true
```

and the generated code is as follow:

```
/**
   * indicates if this is a cancellation.
   * @return cancellationInd
  **/
  @NotNull
  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "indicates if this is a cancellation")
  public Boolean isCancellationInd() {
    return cancellationInd;
  }

  public void setCancellationInd(Boolean cancellationInd) {
    this.cancellationInd= cancellationInd;
  }
```

The problem is that in my JsonREquest to the serviec, when I used
cancellationInd: null, it passes.... I was expecting some HttpStatus_400
because of the required field. Same thing when field is emtpy instead of null...

```
{
...
  "timstamp": "2019-04-29T13:23:56.123-04:00",
  "cancellationInd": "false",
...

}
```

It looks like the reason is that when the attribute is of type boolean, the generated  one in java is Boolean (which is a wrapper, not primitive, and thus accepts a null)... am I right? Is this is a bug?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you try to annotate the parameter with `@Valid`  in the rest controller ?

Comment: Sure, all the other fields are validated except th ones of type Boolean

Comment: did you apply any solution to fix this?